# Alfresco nested collections

Tags: collections, alfresco

Is it possible to have nested collections within Alfresco?  I'm on Community Edition 3.4.  I'd like to have a collection that contains other collections.

Is there something I need to do while defining the collection in the content model XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** it's not supported out of the box

The data list [model](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/datalistModel.xml) defines `dl:dataListItem` as a child type of `cm:content`, therefore you can't nest data lists the same way you [nest documents into folders](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Child_Associations).

What you could do is to create a custom [peer association](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Peer_.28Non-Child.29_Associations) between data lists, in order to create your own nesting logic. This would require refactoring the Share UI components that handle list to let them get knowledge of such a [custom model](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Step_by_Step_Model_Definition), and show nested lists appropriately.

Comment: I've played around with a few options, but this makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is define your own custom constraint.

Instead of using the predefined LIST constraint, you could refer to a Java class.
[Here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Model_Constraints#Writing_Further_Constraints) is a link to the Wiki

So you could define a nested collection. But to present this in either Explorer or Share, you'd have to write new renderers/generators(explorer) or new share template for that specific field.